# How to export a variable inside render function (React JS)?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Something extends React.component{
render(){
const a = this.state.details.map((detail) => (
      <Home key={detail.id} login={detail} />
));
return(/* Some code */)
}
```

How to export **const a** inside the render function and use it inside another **sample.js** folder?

Comment: You can passe it as a props, check this url :
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like :

```
class Something extends React.component{
render(){

const a = this.state.details.map((detail) => (
      <Home key={detail.id} login={detail} />
));
return({a})
}
```

and to pass it into another component pass it as props like :

```
return(<Sample a = {a}/>)
```

and in Sample component use it like `this.props.a`